# windows store app setting

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {

        DateTime mytime = DateTime.Now;
        string time12 = mytime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"); // time 12 hours
        string Use24H = mytime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");   // time 24 hours
        dititalclock.Text = time12;

    }

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="dititalclock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="537" Width="1366" FontSize="300" FontFamily="Digital-7" Margin="0,231,0,0" Foreground="#FFE42525"/>

</Grid>
```

**Setting Page**

```
public sealed partial class SettingsFlyout1 : SettingsFlyout
{
    public SettingsFlyout1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

<SettingsFlyout
x:Class="ClockTest.SettingsFlyout1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ClockTest"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
IconSource="Assets/SmallLogo.png"
Title="SettingsFlyout1"
d:DesignWidth="346">

<!-- This StackPanel acts as a root panel for vertical layout of the content sections -->
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >

    <!-- The StackPanel(s) below define individual content sections -->

    <!-- Content Section 1-->
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource SettingsFlyoutSectionStyle}">

        <!-- Section 1 header -->

        <!-- Section 1 body -->

    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="24 Hours" Height="28" FontSize="25"/>
    <ToggleSwitch x:Name="utctime24" Header="ToggleSwitch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="88" Width="187"/>

    <!-- Define more Content Sections below as necessary -->

</StackPanel>
```

**i want to togle switch on then time display as 24 hours mode , its of then 12 hours an save the setting , if i am close the app start again whiich seeting i am saved that will deafult an run the app (if togle switch on 24 hours mode and close app it setting permanent , togle swich is of then 12 hours mode seeting permanent ) plase help or any sample app for how to app setting work i don't need windows sdk sample its only showing how to add setting , i want how to work with that setting **

Comment: What's not clear in the SDK sample and what have you tried so far?

Comment: yes but sdk sample only showing how to add a setting page , i want add a setting work with that setting

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to save the values in [ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx).[LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx).

Then, when you load the app, you need to populate those fields based on the stored settings. I suggest creating a SettingsViewModel to accomplish this. It can both initialize itself (and read in the data from the settings object) and provide binding accessors for your flyout.